# django-timezones

Tags: python, django, timezone

I am trying to setup django-timezones but am unfamiliar on how to go about this.  The only info that I have found is here: http://www.ohloh.net/p/django-timezones

```
class MyModel(Model): 
    timezone = TimeZoneField() 
    datetime = LocalizedDateTime('timezone')
```

I also tried looking through the pinax code or any other projects that use this app but haven't found anything.

Does anyone have an example or some info that they can share on how to use this?

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 4):

Well, the firs thing you need to do when installing any Django app, is add it to your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py. This particular app doesn't do to much other then give you some handy fields and things that you can use in other parts of your Django project. Your best bet to understand it is reading the source, I would say.